# ^[\w]$ no acepta un texto como "holas". ¿Cómo puedo aceptar letras, tildes, números, espacios y algunos símbolos?

Tags: java, regex

Estoy en un formulario, tengo un campo `jTextField` llamado `jTextField_descripcion`, debe validar esa descripción insertada. Sólo se aceptan letras, tildes, números, `-`, `_`, `/`, y espacios, y debe ser inferior la longitud a 121 caracteres.

```
public static boolean validarDescripcion(String descripcion){
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[\\w]$");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(descripcion);
    if (mat.matches() && (descripcion.length()<121)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if(Validaciones.validarDescripcion("holas"))
    System.out.println("Descripcion valida");
else
    System.out.println("Descripcion NO valida");
```

¿Por qué no lo realiza?
Al ser menor de 121 caracteres tendría que ser válida, ¿no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algunas cosas para corregir en tu código:

- `^` y `$` son redundantes cuando utilizas [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()), ya que este método sólo coincide con todo el string.
- `\w` sólo coincide con 1 único caracter, deberías utilizar repetición para que coincida con más. Para repetirlo entre 1 y más veces, se utilizaría `\w+`. Para repetirlo entre 1 y 120 veces `\w{1,120}`.
- Para agregar más caracteres, simplemente se pueden incorporar en la clase de caracteres: `[-/ \w]{1,120}`.
- `\w` no acepta tildes, `ñ` u otros diacríticos por defecto. Para que se acepten, se debe utilizar el flag [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).

De esta forma, nos quedaría:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
public static boolean validarDescripcion(String descripcion){
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[-/ \\w]{1,120}", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(descripcion);

    return mat.matches();
}
```

Comment: Nunca había entendido tan BIEN una respuesta. Ejemplar documentación, así si se entiende con aclaraciónes. Buen trabajo Mariano. Obviamente funciona a las mil maravillas, incorporé la opción de añadir el punto "." y la coma ",".

Comment: Se puede incorporar cualquier caracter o rango (como `a-z`) dentro de la **[clase de caracteres](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)**. Sólo ten cuidado en mantener el `-` al principio, o escaparlo como `\\-` (para que no lo tome como rango).